# after refresh the page and add new data so newly added data is replaced with old data in the table [javascript]

Tags: javascript, local-storage

here I'm working with `localstorage` in javascript 
here is my code for enter `productDetails` in the table using a form. when i'm enter `productDetails` in the table and refresh the page the entered data is in the table because of localStorage. but my problem is that when I refresh the page and again add new data so that newly added data is replaced with data which is added before refresh the page. and I want all my data instead of replacing

```
let productDetails = {

};

/**
 * this function is for get the value from form
*/
function getValue() {
    let id = document.getElementById('productId').value;
    let partNo = document.getElementById('productNo').value;
    let productName = document.getElementById('productName').value;
    let size = getRadioValue();
    let color = getCheckBoxValue();
    let description = document.getElementById('description').value;
    let date = document.getElementById('date').value;
    let address = document.getElementById('address').value;
    let companyName = document.getElementById('companyName').value;
    return {
        id, partNo, productName, size, color, description, date, address, companyName
    };
}

/**
 * function to insert data into table
 */
function insertion() {
    let value = getValue();
    
    let letter = value.productName[0];
    
    if (!productDetails.hasOwnProperty(letter)) {
        productDetails[letter] = [];
    }
    let object = {
        weight: value.weight, id: value.id, partNo: value.partNo, productName: value.productName, size: value.size, color: value.color, description: value.description,
        companyDetails: {
            date: value.date,
            address: value.address,
            companyName: value.companyName
        }
    };

    JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('productDetails'));
    
    productDetails[letter].push(object);
    localStorage.setItem("productDetails", JSON.stringify(productDetails));
    displayData();
    message("");
 }

/**
 * this function display the data in table
 */
function displayData() {
    objectArray = Object.values(productDetails);
    display(objectArray);
}

/**
 * function to display table
 */
function display() {
    
    var result = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("productDetails"));
    console.log(result)
    messageTable(" ");
    let table = "<table border = 1 cellpadding = 10 ><th colspan=7 >Product Details</th><th colspan=7 >company Details</th><tr><th>weight</th><th>Product Id</th><th>Part No</th><th>Name</th><th>Size</th><th>Color</th><th>Description</th><th>Date</th><th>Address</th><th>Company name</th></tr>";
    for (var key in result) {
        for (var weight in result[key]) {
            //let companyDetails = result[key][weight].companyDetails ? result[key][weight].companyDetails : { date: "", address: "", companyName: "" };
            table += "<tr><td>" + key + "</td>";
            table += "<td>" + result[key][weight].id + "</td>";
            table += "<td>" + result[key][weight].partNo + "</td>";
            table += "<td>" + result[key][weight].productName + "</td>";
            table += "<td>" + result[key][weight].size + "</td>";
            table += "<td>" + result[key][weight].color + "</td>";
            table += "<td>" + result[key][weight].description + "</td>";
            table += "<td>" + result[key][weight].companyDetails.date + "</td>";
            table += "<td>" + result[key][weight].companyDetails.address + "</td>";
            table += "<td>" + result[key][weight].companyDetails.companyName + "</td>";

        }
    } messageTable(table);
    console.log(result)
}
```

Comment: @pwilcox do you have any idea?

Comment: Inside `insertion` function, when you read from the localStorage, you don't save the return value in any variable. You probably meant to store the result in `productDetails` variable that is defined globally.

Comment: @lezabiey it looks you need to assing the localStorage information to productDetails first, because you are always starting with an empty object and so you insert a new object with fresh information to the storage instead of an update on top of the previous one. try something like:
`let productDetails  = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('productDetails'));`

Comment: Unrelated, but you're passing an argument to your display function that you don't actually use.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is add a check looking for the localstorage key for your data when the page loads, if the check is true then add the previous localstorage data to your `productDetails object`. This is the Example =>

```
window.onload = init;
var arr = [];

function init() {
   if(localStorage.getItem("productDetails")) {
         arr.push(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("productDetails")));
         getValue(); /*Then Continue eg.Refer to a function*/
  }
   else {
     getValue();  /*Do something eg.Refer to a function*/ 
  }
}
```

The concept is when the page loads add a `window.onload` function to check whether the localStorage key "productDetails" exists. If the key exist then add/push the value stored by the key to the array `arr` in this example. If it does not exist then eg. Do something like => Refer to a function.